# Explicit formula for recurrence relation with $A_{N+1}= A_N+{(2/7)}^N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can I find a non-recursive formula for the sequence $A_N$ when the sequence is defined as $A_1=1$ and for $N\ge 1$, $A_{N+1}= A_N+{(2/7)}^N$?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the  sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence?

Comment: No, this is all the info I have

Comment: I jus dont know how to find the formula and I need the formula to use a proof by induction in order to prove the statement is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Write it as $$A_{n+1}-A_n=r^n$$ where $r=\frac 2 7$.

Then, summing from $n=1$ to $n=m$; we get that

$$A_{m+1}-A_1=\sum_{n=1}^m r^n$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Comment: Any time. If this question helped you, you can consider upvoting it using the arrows, or accepting it, using the greyed out tick under the vote tally, that will turn green up acception. Cheers.